# phpexcel save file to server ubuntu

Tags: server, save, phpexcel

I'm with a problem I would like to share to see if I can provide help.

PHP Excel use Ubuntu and want guaradar the file generated in a specific folder of my project directory. I understand that looking information is made as follows, but it is not working properly.
My code is as follows:

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    //header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="ReporteSuscriptores.xlsx"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    //$objWriter->save('nameoffile.xls');
    $filename = (__DIR__);
    $objWriter->save($filename . '/report.xlsx');
```

Try other alternatives without success as the next block

```
$objWriter->save('nameoffile.xls');
```

And I can not save the file generated excel in a specific directory

Comment: If you're saving it to disk, discard those headers because they're meaningless because you're not sending the spreadsheet to the browser

Comment: `$objWriter->save('/path/to/wherever/you/want/to/save/the/file/nameoffile.xls');` in exactly the same way that you'd specify a filename with a path for any PHP Filesystem function

Comment: Thank you. The problem was due to lack of permissions.